# Optimizing search of all the shortest paths in a Graph with N vertices and N edges

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, shortest-path

I need to find the shortest paths between all pairs in a Graph `G`. I'm using the Floyd–Warshall algorithm to compute the solution.

I need to know if there is a better option to find all the shortest paths given these facts about `G`:

1. `G` is an undirected graph.
2. The numbers of vertices and the edges is the same.
3. All edge weights are positive.

Is there a better solution than Floyd–Warshall given these facts?

Comment: `The numbers of vertices and the edges is the same` - Does it mean that graph is very sparse?

Comment: I don't know what that mean. (i don't have much background in graph theory)

Comment: That is exactly what i mean

Comment: I would say that #2 implies that the graph has one cycle, and 0 or more "tails".  In that case, it should be fairly easy to beat Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: Does that mean that Floyd-Warshall is the best method to solve the problem in a graph that contains that features ?

Comment: @eli.rodriguez Yes, I reread topic tile now :)

Comment: Is the graph connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MBo @DubioserKerl , This is best approach that a found.

Since there are `N` vertices and `N` edges and the graph is connected , we know that there is only one cycle so , that cycle can be in a way "compressed" and save the "contentedness" of that cycle with the rest of the graph.

For example in the next graph the we can substitute the cycle `c-d-e-g` and create a new node `h` and save all externals the relation of the cycle

```
a -> c
b -> d
f -> g
```

, so if we need find to paths between `a` and `b` we need

1. Find the paths `a - b` in the collapsed graph using an LCA algoriths based to find the shortest path.
2. And find the shortest paths between `d - c` in the cycle

[image]

I hope been clear enough the implementation is here

Answer (score 4):

There is modification of Dijkstra Shortest Path algorithm for sparse graphs that works very fast and reveals log-linear (close to linear) asymptotic behavior. You need N searches from N vertices that gives O(N^2*LogN) asymptotic time that is better than O(N^3) Floyd–Warshall algorithm.

Probably your graph has special topology that allows more efficient approaches...

[C++ code with Russian description](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dijkstra_sparse) (may be translated by Google Chrome)

I have delphi implementation for grid graph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355114/optimisation-of-a-dijkstra-shortest-path-search-in-delphi/22376696#22376696).

Comment: The graph represent routes , and as far as i know there is no any special beyond that features that i list.

Comment: OK, I did that implementation for road graph.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Johnson's Algorithm? It seems to solve exactly your problem, i.e. APSP on a sparse weighted graph (with no circles of negative weight)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yes i do , but the test show that Floyd-Warshall is far more efficient

Comment: But since i don't have and extensive background in algorithms but is Johnson's on his core is basically and execute Dijkstra algorithm over every pair ? is That correct ?